# Factorization of $f(z)=(e^z-1)^{12}\sin{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am given a function $f: G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, where $f\in\mathcal{H}(G)$, and where $f$ is not identically zero. Now if we assume that $f(a)=0$, we know that we can put $f$ on the form
$$f(z)=(z-a)^ng(z)$$
where $g(a)\neq0$. My goal is now to find the number $n$ above, for the function
$$f(z)=(e^z-1)^{12}\sin{z}$$
where we have $a=0$. My initial observation was that we can rewrite
$$f(z)=(e^z-e^0)^{12}\sin{z}$$
and taking the principal log on both sides we get
$$\log(f(z))=12\log(e^z-e^0)+\log(\sin{z})$$
However this seems to take me nowhere, i felt i was going the right way, since i basically want the $z-0$ down from the exponents.

This is not a homework question, but a preperation before my exam, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hint: $
f(z) = z^{13} \left( {\frac{{e^z  - 1}}{z}} \right)^{12} \frac{{\sin z}}{z}
$.

Comment: @Gary Ah! I think i am following, but please correct me if im wrong. $\frac{\sin{z}}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z\rightarrow0$, and so does $(\frac{e^z-1}{z})^{12}$, which means we get a function with $g(a)\neq 0$, and then it follows that $n=13$, right?

Comment: @Gary You should post this as answer.

Comment: @kumalka Yes, correct!

Answer (score 1):

From the hint @Gary gave, by using that
$$f(z)=z^{13}\left(\frac{e^z-1}{z}\right)^{12}\frac{\sin{z}}{z}$$
we know that $\sin{z}/{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z\rightarrow 0$, and so does $\left(\frac{e^z-1}{z}\right)^{12}$, this means that their product form $g(z)$, and thus $n=13$